# Primitive pattern matching in R

Tags: r

I have become confused over the following lines of code:

```
test1 = c(0.3, 0.1)
test1 = test1 - 0.1
test2 = c(0.2, 0.0)
test1 == test2
# [1] FALSE  TRUE
```

I think it is quite self explaining why this seems very weird. If anybody could give some insight into what is happening here it would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You can check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9508518/why-are-these-numbers-not-equal)

Comment: Quick insight: see output of `test1 - test2`.

Comment: try using `all.equal`